# Transpose multiple column into rows using case condition

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot, case, transpose

I have a SQL Query below

```
select 
row_number()
OVER (ORDER BY hapf.position_code) Identifier,
hapf.position_code as position_code,
pg.name as gradename,
pgsfv.name as stepname
from
hr_all_positions_f hapf, PER_VALID_GRADES_F pvgf, per_grades pg, PER_GRADE_STEPS_F_VL pgsfv
where
hapf.position_id = pvgf.position_id
and pvgf.grade_id = pg.grade_id
and pgsfv.grade_id = pg.grade_id
and hapf.position_code = 'PRGUSPOS084'
and TO_CHAR(hapf.effective_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '4712-12-31'
```

Output is below

```
Identifier  Position_Code  Gradename  Stepname
1           PRGUSPOS084    Salary05   Step01
2           PRGUSPOS084    Salary05   Step02
3           PRGUSPOS084    Salary05   Step03
4           PRGUSPOS084    Salary06   Step01
5           PRGUSPOS084    Salary06   Step02
6           PRGUSPOS084    Salary06   Step03
7           PRGUSPOS084    Salary07   Step01
8           PRGUSPOS084    Salary07   Step02
9           PRGUSPOS084    Salary07   Step03
```

I have used case when condition to convert the GradeName column to rows like below

SQL

```
    select 
row_number()
OVER (ORDER BY position_code) RN,
position_code as pos,
--stepname as step,
max(case when Identifier = 1 then gradename end) as Grade1,
max(case when Identifier = 2 then gradename end) as Grade2,
max(case when Identifier = 3 then gradename end) as Grade3
from
(
select 
row_number()
OVER (ORDER BY hapf.position_code) Identifier,
hapf.position_code as position_code,
pg.name as gradename,
pgsfv.name as stepname
from
hr_all_positions_f hapf, PER_VALID_GRADES_F pvgf, per_grades pg, PER_GRADE_STEPS_F_VL pgsfv
where
hapf.position_id = pvgf.position_id
and pvgf.grade_id = pg.grade_id
and pgsfv.grade_id = pg.grade_id
and hapf.position_code = 'PRGUSPOS084'
and TO_CHAR(hapf.effective_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '4712-12-31'
) x
group by position_code
```

Output with this query is below

```
RN  POS           GRADE1      GRADE2      GRADE3
1   PRGUSPOS084   Salary 05   Salary 06   Salary 07
```

But I want output as below

```
NO  POS           GRADE1      GRADE2      GRADE3       Grade1Step1    Grade1Step2    Grade1Step3    Grade2Step1    Grade2Step2    Grade2Step3    Grade3Step1    Grade3Step2    Grade3Step3
1   PRGUSPOS084   Salary 05   Salary 06   Salary 07    Step01         Step02         Step03         Step01         Step02         Step03         Step01         Step02         Step03
```

How is it possible to use another case statement ?

I tried the below but the output is not correct, please help.

```
    select
pos,
Grade1,
Grade2,
Grade3, 
max(case when RN = 1 then step end) as stepname1,
max(case when RN = 2 then step end) as stepname2,
max(case when RN = 3 then step end) as stepname3
from
(
    select 
    row_number()
    OVER (ORDER BY position_code) RN,
    position_code as pos,
    stepname as step,
    max(case when Identifier = 1 then gradename end) as Grade1,
    max(case when Identifier = 2 then gradename end) as Grade2,
    max(case when Identifier = 3 then gradename end) as Grade3
    from
    (
    select 
    row_number()
    OVER (ORDER BY hapf.position_code) Identifier,
    hapf.position_code as position_code,
    pg.name as gradename,
    pgsfv.name as stepname
    from
    hr_all_positions_f hapf, PER_VALID_GRADES_F pvgf, per_grades pg, PER_GRADE_STEPS_F_VL pgsfv
    where
    hapf.position_id = pvgf.position_id
    and pvgf.grade_id = pg.grade_id
    and pgsfv.grade_id = pg.grade_id
    and hapf.position_code = 'PRGUSPOS084'
    and TO_CHAR(hapf.effective_end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '4712-12-31'
    ) x
    group by position_code
    , stepname
) z group by pos, Grade1, Grade2, Grade3
```

Comment: Your first query will get `Salary05` for all three grade positions. Are you always expecting exactly, or at least a maximum of, three grades per position, and three steps per position/grade? (And is the 9th row in your output supposed to be `Salary07`, not `Salary05`?)

Comment: Thanks for reply, the values in stepname column are just for reference I can't put a maximum clause. there are other values attached with respect to stepname so need to pull out specific stepname for specific gradename in a single row. and you are correct the 9th row has a Typo mistake, I will correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call multiple analytic functions inside your inner query, with different [partition-by clauses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html), instead of just one; and then work from those - combing the analytic ranking of the grades and steps within the case expressions.

As I don't have your base tables I've given the fixed values from your sample as a further inner query to demonstrate the idea, with a single extra value to show a second row of output:

```
select position_num,
  position_code,
  max(case when grade_num = 1 then grade_name end) as grade1,
  max(case when grade_num = 2 then grade_name end) as grade2,
  max(case when grade_num = 3 then grade_name end) as grade3,
  max(case when grade_num = 1 and grade_step_num = 1 then step_name end) as Grade1Step1,
  max(case when grade_num = 1 and grade_step_num = 2 then step_name end) as Grade1Step2,
  max(case when grade_num = 1 and grade_step_num = 3 then step_name end) as Grade1Step3,
  max(case when grade_num = 2 and grade_step_num = 1 then step_name end) as Grade2Step1,
  max(case when grade_num = 2 and grade_step_num = 2 then step_name end) as Grade2Step2,
  max(case when grade_num = 2 and grade_step_num = 3 then step_name end) as Grade2Step3,
  max(case when grade_num = 3 and grade_step_num = 1 then step_name end) as Grade3Step1,
  max(case when grade_num = 3 and grade_step_num = 2 then step_name end) as Grade3Step2,
  max(case when grade_num = 3 and grade_step_num = 3 then step_name end) as Grade3Step3
from (
  select 
    dense_rank() over (order by position_code) position_num,
    position_code,
    grade_name,
    step_name,
    dense_rank() over (partition by position_code order by grade_name) as grade_num,
    dense_rank() over (partition by position_code, grade_name order by step_name) as grade_step_num
  from
  (
    select 'PRGUSPOS084' as position_code, 'Salary05' as grade_name, 'Step01' as step_name from dual
    union all select 'PRGUSPOS084', 'Salary05', 'Step02' from dual
    union all select 'PRGUSPOS084', 'Salary05', 'Step03' from dual
    union all select 'PRGUSPOS084', 'Salary06', 'Step01' from dual
    union all select 'PRGUSPOS084', 'Salary06', 'Step02' from dual
    union all select 'PRGUSPOS084', 'Salary06', 'Step03' from dual
    union all select 'PRGUSPOS084', 'Salary07', 'Step01' from dual
    union all select 'PRGUSPOS084', 'Salary07', 'Step02' from dual
    union all select 'PRGUSPOS084', 'Salary07', 'Step03' from dual
    union all select 'PRGUSPOS085', 'Salary06', 'Step02' from dual
  )
)
group by position_num, position_code;
```

which gets:

```
POSITION_NUM POSITION_CO GRADE1   GRADE2   GRADE3   GRADE1 GRADE1 GRADE1 GRADE2 GRADE2 GRADE2 GRADE3 GRADE3 GRADE3
------------ ----------- -------- -------- -------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
           1 PRGUSPOS084 Salary05 Salary06 Salary07 Step01 Step02 Step03 Step01 Step02 Step03 Step01 Step02 Step03
           2 PRGUSPOS085 Salary06                   Step02
```

So your real query might end up as something like:

```
select position_num,
  position_code,
  max(case when grade_num = 1 then grade_name end) as grade1,
  max(case when grade_num = 2 then grade_name end) as grade2,
  max(case when grade_num = 3 then grade_name end) as grade3,
  max(case when grade_num = 1 and grade_step_num = 1 then step_name end) as Grade1Step1,
  max(case when grade_num = 1 and grade_step_num = 2 then step_name end) as Grade1Step2,
  max(case when grade_num = 1 and grade_step_num = 3 then step_name end) as Grade1Step3,
  max(case when grade_num = 2 and grade_step_num = 1 then step_name end) as Grade2Step1,
  max(case when grade_num = 2 and grade_step_num = 2 then step_name end) as Grade2Step2,
  max(case when grade_num = 2 and grade_step_num = 3 then step_name end) as Grade2Step3,
  max(case when grade_num = 3 and grade_step_num = 1 then step_name end) as Grade3Step1,
  max(case when grade_num = 3 and grade_step_num = 2 then step_name end) as Grade3Step2,
  max(case when grade_num = 3 and grade_step_num = 3 then step_name end) as Grade3Step3
from (
  select 
    dense_rank() over (order by hapf.position_code) position_num,
    hapf.position_code,
    pg.name as grade_name,
    pgsfv.name as step_name,
    dense_rank() over (partition by hapf.position_code order by pg.name) as grade_num,
    dense_rank() over (partition by hapf.position_code, pg.name order by pgsfv.name)
      as grade_step_num
  from
  hr_all_positions_f hapf
  join per_valid_grades_f pvgf on hapf.position_id = pvgf.position_id
  join per_grades pg on pvgf.grade_id = pg.grade_id
  join per_grade_steps_f_vl pgsfv on pgsfv.grade_id = pg.grade_id
  where hapf.position_code = 'PRGUSPOS084'
  and hapf.effective_end_date = date '4712-12-31'
)
group by position_num, position_code;
```

I've taken the liberty of switching your inner query to use modern join syntax; and to compare your `effective_end_date` with an actual date, rather than converting it to a string - which is generally a bad idea as it would prevent an index on that column being used.

Comment: You are awesome man !! Thanks big time. It worked so smoothly.. Thanks again